# AngularJS 1.4.8 - Call my web service only on ng-blur if the value changed

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox that should call a web service on blur, but only if the value changes

I tried `ng-change` , but it call the service on the first button down.
I tried `ng-blur`, but it calls the service even if the value did not change.

`ng-blur="SetProgress(Id, Progress)"`

How can I call the service when i'm done editing the value and the value has changed.

Thanks

Comment: you could use [$asyncValidators](http://www.codelord.net/2014/11/02/angularjs-1-dot-3-taste-async-validators/) for your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A directive would solve this:

```
.directive('saveOnBlur', [
    function () {
        return {
            scope: { saveOnBlur: '&' },
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                elem.on('blur', function () {
                    if (ngModel.$dirty) {
                        console.log('model is dirty, saving');
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.saveOnBlur();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

In your HTML you use it like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="scopeProp" save-on-blur="save()">
```

codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/LGxvMo?editors=100